# Resizing Div with position absolute defined

Tags: html, css, image, css-position, image-resizing

I'm trying to auto resize the  elements with images on it and using position at the same time. Works fine in a PC screen but it does not works with cellphone or even when the PC screen is resized.

So, here is the html:

```
    <div class="main-container">
        <div class="relative">
            <img src="../imgs/header_single.jpg" alt="header" class="img-header">
        
            <div class="overlap" >
                    <img src="../imgs/compra-online.png" alt="goomer" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
```

CSS:

```
.main-container{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 2rem ;
}

.relative{
    position: relative
}

.img-header{
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    position: relative;
}

.overlap{
    position: absolute;
    width: 360px; 
    height: 219px;
    top: 3rem;
    left: 1.25rem;
}
```

[Normal Size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G4xRZ.png)

When I resize the screen, the overlap class does not resize. Already tried to put height: auto but it does not work. I'm new on this. Can anyone helpe me on how to dinamically resize the overlap div?

[Resized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzeTd.png)

Comment: So summing up, what do you want to do? Make the second image a little bit down or rise the upper image?

Comment: I want to keep the proportions of the image on the class overlap when the screen is resized.